# Migrating SOAP functionality from PHP to Perl using SOAP::WSDL

Tags: perl, soap

I'm struggling to get SOAP working in perl.

In PHP it works perfectly, and without any trouble. And now I'm trying to do the same thing in Perl.

The functional PHP is:

```
$client = new SoapClient("http://thirdpartyurl.com/api.aspx?WSDL");
$info = $client->GetSomeInfo(array('username' => 'myusername', 'password' => 'mypassword'));
```

Which works great, but I just can't get it working in perl. I tried SOAP::Lite, but didn't make any progress. And I'm now trying SOAP::WSDL:

```
use SOAP::WSDL;
my $wsdl = SOAP::WSDL->new(wsdl => 'http://thirdpartyurl.com/api.aspx?WSDL');
my $info = $wsdl->call('GetSomeInfo', 'username', 'myusername', 'password', 'mypassword');
```

Which just doesn't work.
I looked at the raw requests, and the perl version isn't even sending the user/pass parameters through. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "Just doesn't work" is NOT an appropriate way to ask, IMHO. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Similar question to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1748921/calling-functions-with-parameters-using-soap-with-perl

Comment: @Leonardo, I've been succinct as I can be! I really don't know what more information I can give. I've used tcpdump to look at the raw requests going out and the parameters aren't in there. I just don't know what to try next.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For what it's worth, I achieved authentication, and managed to get parameters sent by using the following:

```
use SOAP::Lite;
my $service = SOAP::Lite->proxy($service_url)->uri($service_url);

sub SOAP::Transport::HTTP::Client::get_basic_credentials {
    return 'myusername' => 'mypassword';
}

my $result = $service->insert(
    SOAP::Data->name(
        'data' => \SOAP::Data->value(
            SOAP::Data->name(
                'item' => \SOAP::Data->value(
                    SOAP::Data->name('key' => 'name'),
                    SOAP::Data->name('value' => 'new_campaign_x')
                )
            )
        )
    )->type('Map')
);
```

Is there a better way to achieve the same results? I realise overwriting 'get_basic_credentials' is a bit hacky.

Answer (score 0):

I've had pretty good luck with SOAP::Lite in my applications.  The username/password combo, is that supposed to be authenticating at the HTTP layer or the SOAP layer?  Or just regular soap parameters?

Answer (score -1):

When I want to do SOAP, I reach for [XML::Compile](http://search.cpan.org/dist/XML-Compile).